# Running an OpenCV program with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, opencv, build, launch

I'm trying to run a simple example of OpenCV on Eclipse [which was perfectly buit and installed before (using CMake and MinGw), even libraries and all includes are in place !].
When building, I'm getting no errors or warning, all seems good, but when I try to run, I get a message as if the project had no Binaries, even if all binaries are there. I even specified the path to the ".exe" (run->run conf-> new launch-> browse ...etc.).
You can notice on the images attached that the project is built and the binaries are generated.
Notice: when I run an example of a (Hellow world) on the console ... it displays the messag without errors.

I read a lot on Internet before posting here, but I found nothing that matches to this case.
Thank you so much,
[Error Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpSxf.jpg)
[Build Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyItF.jpg)
Regards

Comment: You can click the details button `Details>>>`, to get the info about errors. Right?

Comment: yes it just says "no binaries"